# if a resource value is missing in one resx file will it use the same value from the default resx file

Tags: asp.net, resources, resx

Just a simple question,

if i have several resource files for a page (contains strings for each language set) and one of those files is missing a particular string, will the string be taken from another resource file automatically to fill the gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your culture specific resource file don't contain the key, asp.net will automatically search for that key in the default resource file.

Answer (score 1):

It will use the value from the default resx-file.